# Determining source of method call at runtime

Tags: php, oop

I'm wondering if there is a "better" way to do this:

```
class Foo {
    final public function bar() {
        if (is_subclass_of(get_called_class(), __CLASS__)) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function baz() {
        parent::bar(); // shouldn't be allowed
    }
}
```

Essentially, I want certain methods in my parent class to prohibit child classes from calling them.  This needs to be bullet-proof, which I doubt this is, so if you know how this could be circumvented, that's what I'm interested in knowing (along with how to prevent it, if possible).

**Edit:**  For everyone suggesting private methods, this is not an option, as I need the interface to remain public to be externally accessible.  Sorry, I guess I assumed that would be obvious.

Comment: Erm, making it `private` does this?

Comment: A function that can be called publicly by anyone, but not by the object itself? That's rather... weird. Maybe you're trying to defend a little too vigorously against your own programers/subclassers? :)

Comment: In that case: I would say if you _need_ this it is a design problem, and `Bar` shouldn't inherit from `Foo` in the first place... But let's try some methods. Is an instance method (`$this->bar()`) also not allowed or only a call to `parent::bar()`?

Comment: @deceze: I have a very good reason for wanting this behavior.  I'm trying to make a learning "game" whereby participants extend a parent class and submit their new child class which is then injected into the game.  I want these submitted classes to be somewhat sandboxed, so they can't cheat and break the game for other participants (as much as plausible within the limitations of PHP).

Comment: @Wrikken: Any invocation of the `bar()` method should be disallowed *if it's invoked within a child class method.*

Comment: Then making that the actual question may be better. I'd probably not allow the use of real class extensions to begin with, but analyze the submitted source code with a tokenizer and check that only certain allowed APIs are called. That's just of the top off my head though... :)

Comment: Even tokenizing would have trouble with it, like `$foo="bar";$this->$foo();`, and myriad others.

Comment: @deceze: That would make it very convoluted to try and enforce the class interface, though, I think.  But you're right, it would probably be safer.  I was hoping I could do something reasonably safe without resorting to that kind of complexity, though.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) of what I'm trying to make, if anyone is familiar with it.  It uses Java, rather than PHP, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Foo {
    final public function bar() {
        if (is_subclass_of(get_called_class(), __CLASS__)) {
            throw new Exception('No cookies for you!');
        }
        echo 'Failure!';
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function baz() {
        try{
                Foo::bar(); // shouldn't be allowed
        } catch (Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        try{
                $func = function() {Foo::bar();}; // is allowed, nags somewhat about it should't be called statically..
                $func();
        } catch (Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
$b = new Bar();
$b->baz();
```

Comment: Ah.. closures never crossed my mind.  Is there a way to prevent this, or alter my design to disallow it?  +1

Comment: This particular one with calling `debug_backtrace()` and stepping through it. I will counter you by calling `register_shutdown_function($func);`....

Comment: Touche.  I think I'm going to have to do some more research on sandboxing, disallowing certain functions, etc.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

This is not going to be "bulletproof". And I don't think there's anything you can do to make it so.

Fact of the matter is, a PHP process is usually running in an interpreter with filesystem access to the local server - as a relatively-unprivileged user. But that's still enough to open `/proc/self/mem`, which provides read-write access to the memory space of the current process. Using that, you could go into the memory the PHP interpreter is using and `NOP` over the bit of code you thought was providing your bulletproof security.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this helps, but private functions in parent classes cant be called by child classes. But if you need it to be public i think you would have to declare `baz()` in each child and throw an exception...

Comment: I edited my question.. private is not an option.  Also, neither is modifying child classes, as those aren't created by me.